# How to orderby Time datatype in sqlite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I as having time in hh:mm aa format ex: 01:30 AM.

While creating table I am specifying the datatype as TIME. But there is no way of setting its format. By default it is HH:MM:SS format. So while entering AM/PM values it is not added in database.

Is there a way to store my time in my required format using TIME datatype column so that sorting can be done easier.

Also I tried saving the time as TEXT datatype. I order it by taking substirng of AM/PM and do string sorting. The problem in it is 12:30 PM will be not correctly ordered.

ex:  12.30 PM, 12.30 AM, 02.30 PM will be ordered as 12.30 AM,02.30 PM,12.30 PM

How can I order this column and what datatype can I give for this?

Comment: That's why the **24 hrs format is better**: `02:30 PM = 14:00`, which comes AFTER 12:30. And 12:30 AM is really `00:30`.

Comment: It may be A trick first U save the data in the TIME TYPE but prior to save just the 01:30 AM just parse the 01:30 and save in TIME TYPE and when in 2:30 PM means according to 24 HRS TIME it 14:30 Would be save it .and then when U retrieve SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY  to_Time(Time) and again re-parse as u need   **SO ITS BETTER TO USE 24 hrs FORMAT**

Comment: Refer this solution:-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45240886/4024250

Answer (score 0):

Use `hh:mm:ss` for storing values in the database.
(It's required for correct sorting, and by all [built-in time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).)

Use the `hh:mm aa` format (or any other format) for displaying values.
You cannot forsee what format is the default for your user's locale, or if the user has selected another time format, so you must be prepared to format times for displaying them in any case.