# How to order by date/time with AM/PM in SQLITE

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, datetime, swift3

My date format is: "yyyy-MM-dd" (2017-03-23)

My time format is: "hh:mm a" (10:15 pm)

If in MYSQL you can perform this to convert time with am/pm:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(timeField,'%h.%i%p');
```

How can you perform this in SQLITE?

I tried this but didn't work:

```
SELECT appointment_date, start_time FROM appointment order by appointment_date, DATE(start_time, '%h:%i %p')
```

Result:
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA08Z.png)

Supposedly AM should be first than PM because the default is ASC, I tried using DESC as well but it didn't properly arranged the result.

Comment: You should be storing that appointment time as a date-with-time value.  Or, if the time is separate, it should be in 24-hour format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be storing the `start_time()` value in a string.

You can do:

```
order by appointment_date,
         (case when start_time like '% am' then 1 else 2 end),
         start_time
```

SQLite doesn't really support am/pm in date/time formats.  But, this is easy enough to accomplish with `like`.

Comment: This works but problem comes when time is 12:30PM and 1:30PM. In this case 1:30PM will come first and other one second because it compares number also and here 1:30<12:30 but as per actual time 1:30PM>12:30PM.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution would be to store your time in 24 hour format in one more column and that column should be of type DATETIME not varchar.

You can convert your time using:

```
        SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mma");
        Date date=new Date();
        try {
            date = parseFormat.parse(AmPmTimeFormatColumn);
        }catch (Exception e){}
        values.put("24HourFormatColumn", displayFormat.format(date));
```

Then order like this:

select * from table_name order by DATETIME(24HourFormatColumn);

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    Date
    , cast(substr(Date, 12, 2) as int) as HOUR
    , substr(Date, 21, 2) as TIME_FORMAT
    , 
        case
            when 
                substr(Date, 21, 2) = 'PM' AND cast(substr(Date, 12, 2) as int) = 12
                then cast(substr(Date, 12, 2) as int)
            when 
                substr(Date, 21, 2) = 'PM'
                then cast(substr(Date, 12, 2) as int) + 12
            when 
                substr(Date, 21, 2) = 'AM' AND cast(substr(Date, 12, 2) as int) = 12
                then 0

            when 
                substr(Date, 21, 2) = 'AM'
                then cast(substr(Date, 12, 2) as int)
        END AS ARMY_HOUR
    , cast(substr(Date, 15, 2) as int) AS MINUTE
from appointment
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).